# Check if argument exists in macro

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

I want to check if there is an argument in my macro command and if there is no argument, do not perform my macro code. In FASM, it looks like:

```
F    MACRO  arg1
if ~ arg eq
mov ax, arg1
add ax,ax
add ax, 5
end if
ENDM
```

But assembling this code returns an error:

> (19) illegal instruction: if ~ arg eq or wrong parameters.

How can I rewrite this macro so it works in emu8086?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used Emu8086, but from what I can tell online, it has a built-in assembler that is compatible with MASM and TASM syntax. In that case, you would use the [`IFB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/ifb) (if symbol is blank) and [`IFNB`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/ifnb) (if symbol is *not* blank) conditional directives.

Therefore, your `F` macro would then be written as following:

```
F MACRO arg1
IFNB <arg1>         ; if arg1 is not blank/empty
    mov ax, arg1
    add ax, ax
    add ax, 5
ENDIF
ENDM F
```

Comment: Well then clearly emu8086 is not fully MASM compatible. It may not support what you want. This is a pretty advanced macro capability.